# Black screen: Ctrl + alt + F(s) or Ctrl + alt + Fn + F(s) not working after login on Ubuntu 18.04 bionic

Tags: nvidia, graphics

After the login screen of my Ubuntu 18.04 the screen turns black. This has to do with my latest installations of Cuda and Nvidia's drivers for my GTX 1080 Ti.

I want to be able to remove the drivers so I can get my GUI back, however, after logging in, I am unable to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F(1,2,3 ... 6)</kbd> or even when combined with Fn: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F(1,2,...)</kbd>.

Please, I completely lost control of the command line since these shortcuts do not seem to work. I have searched thoroughly the internet for comments on this issue, but I could not find a workaround.

Anyone has any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: Usually works here for black screen on our old Intel mobo: `Alt+SysRq+b` [ https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key ]  
If you don't have the `SysRq key`, try print screen key instead: `Alt+PrtSc+b`. Machine will reboot.

Comment: [https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2016/07/key-to-show-grub-menu-ubuntu]

Comment: Hi , I have the same issue , how did your solve the problem ? Im stuck in blackscreen

Answer (score 0):

Since you say. "I completely lost control of the command line since these shortcuts do not seem to work."

For command line

- From grub boot menu (if you don't get grub boot menu keep <kbd>Shift</kbd> pressed after starting the computer)
- Select Advanced Options and enter.
- Select ...(Recovery Mode) and enter and boot.
- Select 'root  Drop to root shell prompt' and enter.
- Press enter for maintenance.
- Root shell will open. Run the commands you want to remove the drivers.

Comment: Which commands mate?